# Can't view the class that i am trying to open in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi could any one help me, 
Ive been trying to figure out why when I click to open a class in eclipse(from the package explorer) the class doesn't open? Its as if it does open but then disappears somewhere. 
I have no errors on my project with regards to why its not opening it just won't open. I can't add a picture of whats on my screen as i don't have the rep.

I have my package explorer on the left hand side and i have my log cat etc down the bottom.

when i click normally it opens in the middle of the page but its stopped doing it.

I have reset my views, i have restarted my mac i have tried closing and opening the perspective and reseting it still nothing works.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [the Eclipse Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/). Also, if you post a link to an image then someone with enough rep can edit your post and add it.

Comment: Ah ok thank's Ill see what i can do. And will defiantly look on the eclipse forum @codeMagic

Comment: Is it a single class or multiple classes that is giving you this problem?

Comment: Its all of my classes, when ever i click them they appear to open but i can't see them.@codeMagic

Comment: You probably messed up your windows do this `Window > Reset Perspective`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is an problem with eclipse. your editor window is not showing. I hope screen looks grey-ish.
I have come across this issue once. Restarting eclipse helped in my case.

- try opening window->New Editor
- try restarting eclipse

Comment: upload screenshot somewhere and paste the link.

Comment: Thanks i tried what you said and worked like a charm :D